# Display unpushed commits in git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I know there is some questions already around there as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits). In my case:

Let's say I have a repo R1 with a submodule SR2.

1. I do a submodule commit in SR2.
2. I commit the submodule update in R1
3. I push the submodule update in R1
4. **I forgot to push in SR2**

Then anyone who will clone repository R1 will get a `reference is not a tree` error, because obviously the submodule commit revision is only available locally currently.

If I then type `git status` in R1 repository, nothing warns me about the fact that my submodule is ahead of the remote repository.

If there any way to retrieve status recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a [`git submodule foreach` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule):

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git status  && echo'
```

You have other commands to show you the status of submodules in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730918/6309), for changes in progress.

---

The [OP Cqnqrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906123/cqnqrd) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547810/display-unpushed-commits-in-git-submodules/24548122?noredirect=1#comment38054356_24548122):

To have better readability, I tweaked it a bit to the following alias:

Multiple-lines:

```sh
gss_command='git -c color.status=always status -s | \
             sed "s/^\(.*\)/\t\1/g" && git branch -v | \
             grep -E "ahead|behind" | \
             sed -r "s/[ *]\s(\S*).*(\[(ahead|behind).+?\]).*/\t\1 \2/g"' 

alias gs="git rev-parse --show-toplevel && \
          $gss_command && \
          git submodule foreach --recursive '$gss_command'"
```

one-liners:

```sh
gss_command='git -c color.status=always status -s | sed "s/^\(.*\)/\t\1/g" && git branch -v | grep -E "ahead|behind" | sed -r "s/[ *]\s(\S*).*(\[(ahead|behind).+?\]).*/\t\1 \2/g"' 

alias gs="git rev-parse --show-toplevel && $gss_command && git submodule foreach --recursive '$gss_command'"
```

Comment: To have better readibility, I tweaked it a bit to the following alias: 
`gss_command='git -c color.status=always status -s | sed "s/^\(.*\)/\t\1/g"  && git branch -v | grep -E "ahead|behind" | sed -r "s/[ *]\s(\S*).*(\[(ahead|behind).+?\]).*/\t\1 \2/g"'
alias gs="git rev-parse --show-toplevel && $gss_command && git submodule foreach --recursive '$gss_command'"`

Comment: @Cqnqrd great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Cqnqrd note: `git status --porcelain` is the one supposed to be parsed (see the end of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402/6309)

Comment: agree, but this (by design) lose coloration! It may depends on the usage you will make of it obviously.